# Google Optimize redirect test reloads page

Tags: google-optimize

We have a Google Optimize redirect test running. We noticed that the page is being loaded twice (that is, reloaded by the Google Optimize javascript right after it first loaded) even when there's no redirect taking place and the URL is the same.

Is there any way to turn this off?

Unfortunately, this happens even after we end the particular test (why?). We keep getting these double loads. We really want to avoid this because it's messing with some pages that use session flash messages.

Comment: Hey @gphilip, did you ever get an answer to your question? I have the same problem with a Rails app and google optimize. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. FWIW Google Optimize is shutting down soon so I wouldn't dedicate too much work to this.